# Magerun vs Command line indexer

Tags: reindex, indexer

Is it preferable to run a nightly re-index via the command line or would it be better to run it with Magerun?

(Or doesn't it really make a difference)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

There should be no difference.

Answer (score -2):

It's depends of the total of sku that you have in site

My recommendation is to run the indexer all the time via command line

Thanks

Comment: Why would you recommend this over MageRun?

Comment: My recommendation is to use the default indexer all the time via command line.

Comment: But why would you?

Comment: Very easy. Why to use an extra tool to do something that came by default with magento?